# Develop iOS Application with Company X account and upload to iTunes Connect with Company Y

Tags: ios, app-store

We (Company X) plan to develop an iPhone App for one of our Customers (Company Y). I would now like to use my developer enrollment for my Company X to develop, build and test the application.

When it comes to deployment I need to upload the App to the AppStore using Company Y as Company name/account. How can we do this?

Though this must be a very common scenario (X developing App for Y and selling/uploading under Y's name) I wasn't able to find a howto in the web or Apple FAQs.

Thanks in advance,
Hauzi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Company Y has to create the distribution certificate with their developer account and provide you with all the keys and certificates for that certificate (yes, also with the private keys; that's the downside). You can then import that into your keychain and sign the app for distribution, then send the signed app to Company Y which needs to upload it as usual.

Comment: +1 For being correct, but most customers will just let you use their account, if they don't have the competence themselves and if they do they'll just do it themselves.

Comment: Company Y also need developer licence and paid yearly fee ?

Comment: @virender: Yes. And if Company Y would complain about that, I'd be arguing that discussing about that is surely wasting much more time=money than the $99/year membership fee ;-) Also, there is no other solution if the app is to be released in their name. After all, they'll also collect the money.

Answer (score 4):

It's really simple. You simply use Y's account when you build for distribution. Alternatively you send the source code to Y and let them build and upload to App Store. It's really as simple as it sounds.

Comment: Company Y might not have a Mac to build the app. That was the situation I faced two years ago when I was in the same situation as the poster. And Company Y might not want to give you the password for their account, either.

Comment: @DarkDust The scenario you're describing certainly is possible, but in my experience most customers are more co-operative than that.

Comment: Not in my experience. We had three companies that were not that cooperative. That's why we had to do go the way described in my answer.

Comment: Isn't it possible to build with X account, then obtain an iTunes Connect account from Y and upload the App using that?

Comment: @Hauzi No it has to signed with Y's distribution certificate.